# How to capture the current namespace inside nested functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose one had the following:

```
def outer(foo, bar, baz):
    frobozz = foo + bar + baz

    def inner(x, y, z):
        return dict(globals().items() + locals().items())

    return inner(7, 8, 9)
```

The value returned by `inner` is the dictionary obtained by merging the dictionaries returned by `globals()` and `locals()`, as shown.  In general<sup>1</sup>, this returned value will *not* contain entries for `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and `frobozz`, even though these variables are visible within `inner`, and therefore, arguably belong in `inner`'s namespace.

One way to facilitate the capturing of `inner`'s namespace would be the following kluge:

```
def outer(foo, bar, baz):
    frobozz = foo + bar + baz

    def inner(x, y, z, _kluge=locals().items()):
        return dict(globals().items() + _kluge + locals().items())

    return inner(7, 8, 9)
```

Is there a better way to capture `inner`'s namespace than this sort of kluge?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Unless, that is, variables having those names happen to be present in the current global namespace.</sup>

Comment: `foo` et al. are neither global nor local variables to in `inner`. Rather, they are looked up in the closure created by the definition of `inner`. In that closure, the free variable `foo` (e.g.) would see the value most recently assigned in the scope where `inner` was defined, but it is not part of the namespace defined by `inner`.

Comment: @chepner: I gather from your comment that in my post I'm using the term `namespace` incorrectly.  What I meant by "`inner`'s namespace" is something like "the set of identifiers that are defined within `inner`'s scope, along with their values." In this sense, this set *should* contain `foo`, `bar`, etc.  What should this set of identifier/value pairs be called?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't dynamic, and most likely it's not the best way, but you *could* simply access the variables inside `inner` to add them to its "namespace":

```
def outer(foo, bar, baz):
    frobozz = foo + bar + baz

    def inner(x, y, z):
        foo, bar, baz, frobozz
        return dict(globals().items() + locals().items())

    return inner(7, 8, 9)
```

You could also store the `outer` function's locals into a variable, and use the variable inside `inner`'s return value:

```
def outer(foo, bar, baz):
    frobozz = foo + bar + baz
    outer_locals = locals()
    def inner(x, y, z):
        return dict(outer_locals.items() + globals().items() + locals().items())
    return inner(7, 8, 9)
```